# Find list of strings in UTF-16 hex bin file and record their offset positions

Tags: search, hex, offset, utf-16

Let me preface by saying I am very inexperienced with code. I took some classes a decade+ ago, and can remember some of the basic principles, but that's about it. I don't have a language I am familiar with or actively using. Anyway, onto my question.

I have a list of selected names that I am trying to find in a large .bin master file of names, and for each of those names record their offset positions. There may be multiple matches for each name as well, so I would need it to record each of those positions in a new column (assuming some kind of tabular output).

I can open the .bin file with a hex editor like HxD or HexEditorNeo and see the names in the "decoded text" section. The file is in UTF-16, so HexEditorNeo lets me set that encoding to remove the "." between each character (not an actual period, but just how it's representing the 00 null characters).

I can use the find tool to search a name, and I can see and copy the offset. However, I have a few thousand names, so this is very tedious to do by hand.

Here is an example of the input files and desired output I would have:

Selected_Names.txt

```
John Williams
Howard Shore
Hans Zimmer
```

Master_Name_File.bin

```
47 00 61 00 6E 00 64 00 61 00 6C 00 66 00 00 00
48 00 6F 00 77 00 61 00 72 00 64 00 20 00 53 00 
68 00 6F 00 72 00 65 00 00 00 44 00 61 00 72 00 
6B 00 20 00 4B 00 6E 00 69 00 67 00 68 00 74 00 
00 00 48 00 61 00 6E 00 73 00 20 00 5A 00 69 00 
6D 00 6D 00 65 00 72 00 00 00 4C 00 75 00 6B 00 
65 00 20 00 53 00 6B 00 79 00 77 00 61 00 6C 00 
6B 00 65 00 72 00 00 00 4A 00 6F 00 68 00 6E 00 
20 00 57 00 69 00 6C 00 6C 00 69 00 61 00 6D 00 
73 00 00 00 48 00 6F 00 77 00 61 00 72 00 64 00 
20 00 53 00 68 00 6F 00 72 00 65 00 00 00 48 00 
61 00 6E 00 73 00 20 00 5A 00 69 00 6D 00 6D 00 
65 00 72 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

G.a.n.d.a.l.f...
H.o.w.a.r.d. .S.
h.o.r.e...D.a.r.
k. .K.n.i.g.h.t.
..H.a.n.s. .Z.i.
m.m.e.r...L.u.k.
e. .S.k.y.w.a.l.
k.e.r...J.o.h.n.
 .W.i.l.l.i.a.m.
s...H.o.w.a.r.d.
 .S.h.o.r.e...H.
a.n.s. .Z.i.m.m.
e.r.............
```

Desired Output

```
John Williams, 00 00 00 78
Howard Shore, 00 00 00 10, 00 00 00 94
Hans Zimmer, 00 00 00 42, 00 00 00 AE
```

I was trying to think of what this might look like in code, and came up with the following pseudocode:

```
// get list of names to search for in array
nameArray = read file of selected names to search for // this is from a txt list
nameCount = length(nameArray)
nameCounter = 0

// get master name file
masterNameArray = read master file of names to search within  // this is the hex file in UTF-16
masterNameCount = length(masterNameArray)

// loop through each name we're searching for
while nameCounter <= nameCount

     // start the position over at 0 for each new name we are searching
     offset = 0
     match = 0

     // loop through each position of the nameArray
     while offset <= masterNameCount

          if nameArray(nameCounter) == masterNameArray(nameCounter)  // check if names match. THIS IS HEX, though, so a straight check can't be done. need to convert, as well as account for how much of the array to check (i.e. name length)

               // record current offset position. record in new column for each match, since there may be multiple matches
               masterNamePosition(nameCounter,match) = offset
               match = match + 1
          end if

          offset = offset + 1
     end while

     nameCounter = nameCounter + 1

end while

write masterNamePosition to file
```

Thank you to anyone willing to read though this and help! It means a lot to me!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

name_file = open('Master_Name_File.bin', 'rb').read()
names = open('Selected_Names.txt').read().splitlines()

def h(n):
  s = '%08X' % n
  return ' '.join([s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)])
  
  
for n in names:
  d = n.encode('utf-16le')
  indexes = []
  i = 0
  while i >= 0:
    i = name_file.find(d, i)
    if i >= 0:
      indexes += [i]
      i += 1
  if indexes:
    print(f'{n}, {", ".join([h(i) for i in indexes])}')
```

Output:

```
John Williams, 00 00 00 78
Howard Shore, 00 00 00 10, 00 00 00 94
Hans Zimmer, 00 00 00 42, 00 00 00 AE
```